# Incorrect certificate on hatdash.com / blog.gaming.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, winter-bash, ssl, blog-overflow

It looks like [hatdash.com](https://hatdash.com/) was used during the [2011 Hat Dash](https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/). Both of these links use certificates that are invalid for their domains, making the site show as insecure.